# What order should the books in the Percy Jackson universe be read in?

Tags: suggested-order, percy-jackson, rick-riordan, the-heroes-of-olympus, the-kane-chronicles

There are several dozen novels, short stories and other works set in the same world as Rick Riordan's *Percy Jackson and the Olympians*. Many of them aren't released chronologically in relation to each other. If I was a completely new reader, what would be the best order to read these in?

### Novels:

- *The Lightning Thief*
- *The Sea of Monsters*
- *The Titan's Curse*
- *The Battle of the Labyrinth*
- *The Last Olympian*
- *The Lost Hero*
- *The Son of Neptune*
- *The Mark of Athena*
- *The House of Hades*
- *The Blood of Olympus*
- *The Red Pyramid*
- *The Throne of Fire*
- *The Serpent's Shadow*
- *The Sword of Summer*
- *The Hammer of Thor* (Unreleased)
- *The Hidden Oracle*
- *The Dark Prophecy*
- *The Burning Maze*
- *The Tyrant's Tomb*
- *The Tower of Nero* (Unreleased)

### Short Stories:

- *The Two Headed Guidance Counselor*
- *The Library of Deadly Weapons*
- *My Demon Satyr Tea Party*
- *My Personal Zombie Apocalypse*
- *Percy Jackson and the Stolen Chariot*
- *Percy Jackson and the Bronze Dragon*
- *Percy Jackson and the Sword of Hades*
- *The Diary of Luke Castellan*
- *Percy Jackson and the Staff of Hermes*
- *Leo Valdez and the Quest for Buford*
- *The Son of Magic* (Written by Haley Riordan but still canon)
- *The Son of Sobek*
- *The Staff of Serapis*
- *The Crown of Ptolemy*

### Graphic Novels:

- *The Lightning Thief Graphic Novel*
- *The Sea of Monsters Graphic Novel*
- *The Titan's Curse Graphic Novel*
- *The Lost Hero Graphic Novel*
- *The Red Pyramid Graphic Novel*
- *The Throne of Fire Graphic Novel*

### Other:

- *Percy Jackson's Greek Gods*
- *Percy Jackson's Greek Heroes*
- *Demigods and Monsters* (A book of real-world essays on the original series with an introduction by Riordan)
- *Percy Jackson and the Olympians: The Ultimate Guide*
- *The Kane Chronicles Survival Guide*
- *Camp Half-Blood Classified*
- *Camp Jupiter Classified* (Unreleased)

Let's just ignore the movies and video game.

Comment: lets just ignore the movies and video game. lol. don't know about video games but movies were actually not great though I kinda liked Logan Lerman.....

Comment: Order of release is the best for a new reader. Chronologically, if you're on a **re-read** is interesting, and you get a lot more about the story. Both answers are essentially correct though.

Comment: This is now followed by the "Trials of Apollo" books - which doesn't have Percy in it except the very beginning. Continues on after the last book in this series.

Comment: I see 2/4 books are listed above, sorry - after "The Dark Prophecy" is now "The Burning Maze" and "The Tyrant's Tomb"

Answer (score 10):

### I recommend reading chronologically

Chronological order is usually the best way to avoid spoilers (except in books with lots of time travel, or where characters can see the future…which come to think of it does apply here). This isn’t strictly chronological, though: for some books, it doesn’t make much difference if you read them slightly out of order.

**First, read:**

- *The Diary of Luke Castellan*

  This describes how Luke and Thalia found Annabeth, and as such is set some       years before the main in *Percy Jackson and the Olympians*

**Then, start  *Percy Jackson and the Olympians*:**

- *The Lightning Thief*
- *The Lightning Thief Graphic Novel*

**After this, it should be safe to read**:

- *The Two Headed Guidance Counselor*
- *The Library of Deadly Weapons*
- *My Demon Satyr Tea Party*
- *My Personal Zombie Apocalypse*

  These are interactive novels. I’m not sure where these books are located chronologically, but I don’t *think* they’ll spoil anything that you wouldn’t have learned in the first book.

**We have a short story that occurs after  *The Lightning Thief*:**

- *Percy Jackson and the Stolen Chariot*

**Then return to the main series**:

- *The Sea of Monsters*
- *The Sea of Monsters Graphic Novel*

**Another short story:**

- *Percy Jackson and the Bronze Dragon*

  This provides useful background for events that occur in *The Lost Hero*, but if you like surprises you might want to hold off until after that novel.

**Back to *Percy Jackson and the Olympians***

- *The Titan’s Curse*
- *The Titan’s Curse Graphic Novel*
- *The Battle of the Labyrinth*
- *The Battle of the Labyrinth Graphic Novel*

**Next is:**

- *The Red Pyramid*
- *The Red Pyramid Graphic Novel*

**Apparently this short story happens *during The Red Pyramid*:**

- *Percy Jackson and the Sword of Hades*

**Then is the second book in the Kane Chronicles**:

- *The Throne of Fire*
- *The Throne of Fire Graphic Novel*
- *The Kane Chronicles Survival Guide*

  This last book was published before *The Serpent’s Shadow*, and should therefore be safe to read here

**Then:**

- *The Last Olympian*
- *The Last Olympian Graphic Novel*

**Then read**

- *The Son of Magic*

  This story follows a demigod who fought in the Manhattan battle in *The Last Olympian*, and as such should be read after that novel.

**Next is probably:**

- *The Staff of Hermes*
- *Percy Jackson and the Singer of Apollo*

**Back to the Kane Chronicles:**

- *The Serpent’s Shadow*

**After that, we start on *Heroes of Olympus*:**

- *The Lost Hero*
- *Leo Valdez and the Quest for Buford*
- *The Son of Neptune*
- *The Mark of Athena*
- *The House of Hades*
- *The Blood of Olympus*

**You might as well read these afterwards:**

- *Percy Jackson’s Greek Gods*
- *Percy Jackson’s Greek Heroes*
- *Demigods and Monsters*
- *Percy Jackson and the Olympians: The Ultimate Guide*

  Most of these *could* be read earlier, but are probably best enjoyed once one has gained a full appreciation of the Greek side of the Riordanverse.

**Then come:**

- *The Son of Sobek*
- *The Staff of Serapis*
- *The Crown of Ptolemy*

**Then comes the first entry in *Magnus Chase and the Gods of Asgard*:**

- *The Sword of Summer*

  This is out of the order that the chronology in the notes presents it, but *The Sword of Summer* is definitely set before or concurrently with *The Hidden Oracle*. Percy references Annabeth being in Boston:

  > “Annabeth.” I tried to place the name. “She’s the blond scary one?”
  >
  > “That’s her. I promised her specifically that I wouldn’t get myself
  >   killed while she’s gone.”
  >
  > “Gone?”
  >
  > Percy waved vaguely toward the north. “She’s in Boston for a few
  >   weeks. Some family emergency. The point is—”
  >
  > <sub>*The Hidden Oracle*</sub>

  Lest we think that this refers to some meeting between Annabeth and Magnus after the events of *The Hidden Oracle*, *The Hammer of Thor* references the events of that series:

  > ‘There’s a crisis happening,’ Annabeth said. ‘A god fell to earth as a
  >   human. These evil Roman emperors are back, causing trouble.’
  >
  > <sub>*The Hammer of Thor*</sub>

**Then go on to:**

- *The Hidden Oracle*

**Finally:**

- *The Hammer of Thor*
- *The Dark Prophecy*

  These last one has not been released as of the time this answer was written, and as such must be read last. Also, practically speaking, since it is unreleased I don’t really know where it fits in chronologically.

<sub>Note: Graphic novels tend to be less detailed than prose novels, so reading the print version of each novel before the graphic version might help you understand the graphic novel better.</sub>

<sub>Note : I received a great deal of help from [this timeline.](https://snoworld.one/rick-riordans-mythology-timeline-of-events/) It’s not certain, but I’m not going to do all that work over myself.</sub>

Comment: I'd recommend reading in order of release. That way, the things that were supposed to stay a mystery remain a mystery. That way, you read, have questions, then have them answered, instead of reading answers of questions that you don't have yet.

Comment: You have the order wrong chronologically. The sword of summer occurs at the same time as the Trials of Apollo. It is referenced in Trials of Apollo that Annabeth is away on a family emergency. The release order is the best because that is how the writer intended it, you don't have obscure timeline problems and some things happen in parallel like one mentioned above

Comment: @Arcane - Thanks for alerting me of that. I’m seeing some stuff that says the opposite, though…I’m trying to pin down a better time. It doesn’t help that the pop culture references are all over the place.

Comment: Chronologically It is confirmed. In the Hidden Oracle, Percy says that he promised to Anabeth that he won't get himself killed. And then mentions that she is in Boston for some family emergency. In the sword of summer, Anabeth tells Magnus that she and her father rushed when they heard about him from Randolph. That is a family emergency in Boston. There was another reference about Magnus in The House of Hades when Anabeth tells Percy she has a cousin in Boston.

Comment: @Arcane - I found even more clear information that makes that chronology even more obvious. I’ll correct my answer.

Comment: Yup. Anabeth visited back to New York and learnt about the events of the Hidden oracle between the 2 books.

Comment: Note: *The Serpent's Shadow* had to have taken place after *The Lost Hero*, as Drew and Lacy make an appearance and mention that Piper took over.

Answer (score 8):

I would read the main books by order of release so:

- The Lightning Thief
- The Sea of Monsters
- The Titan's Curse
- The Battle of the Labyrinth
- The Last Olympian
- Percy Jackson and the Stolen Chariot
- Percy Jackson and the Bronze Dragon
- Percy Jackson and the Sword of Hades
- The Lost Hero
- The Red Pyramid
- The Son of Neptune
- The Diary of Luke Castellan
- Percy Jackson and the    Staff of Hermes
- Leo    Valdez and the Quest for Buford
- The Son of    Magic
- The Throne of Fire
- The Mark of Athena
- The Serpent's Shadow
- The Son of Sobek
- The Staff of    Serapis
- The House of Hades
- The Blood    of Olympus
- The Two Headed    Guidance Counselor
- The Library of Deadly    Weapons
- My Demon Satyr Tea    Party
- The Crown of Ptolemy
- My Personal    Zombie Apocalypse
- The Sword of    Summer
- The Hidden Oracle
- The Hammer    of Thor (Unreleased)
- The Dark    Prophesy (Unreleased)

The graphic novels should be in the same order as the main books, but I would suggest reading them *after* you read the main books:

- The Lightning Thief Graphic Novel
- The Sea of Monsters Graphic Novel
- The Titan's Curse Graphic Novel
- The Lost Hero Graphic Novel
- The Red Pyramid Graphic Novel
- The Throne of Fire Graphic Novel

All of the 'other' ones should be read after you've read all of the main books.
PJGG and PJGH are the only ones that need an order, PJGG coming first and then PJGH:

- Percy Jackson's Greek Gods
- Percy Jackson's Greek Heroes
- Demigods and Monsters
- Percy Jackson and the Olympians: The Ultimate Guide
- The Kane Chronicles Survival Guide

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would read series that were meant to be in order in the order they were intended. For example, instead of cutting the Kane Chronicles together with Heroes of Olympus just because they were released around the same time, I would read Heroes of Olympus then Kane Chronicles, or vice versa, just because it can be somewhat jarring to jump back and forth between relatively unrelated stories.

Comment: This is mildly confusing. I recommend doing a second pass and editing this answer a bit.