# What is the chronological order of the Demigods and Magicians books?

Tags: rick-riordan

Rick Riordan has written several series of books based on Greek/Roman/Norse Demigods and Egyptian Magicians. If someone wanted to read them in chronological order, how would that flow?

Comment: I wanted to retag this question with [tag:suggested-order] or [tag:chronological-order], but as I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for, I suggest you do that yourself :)

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127892/what-order-should-the-books-in-the-percy-jackson-universe-be-read-in

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/camphalfblood/comments/45x1h8/chronological_order_of_the_books/

Comment: I've also answered this question at Literature.SE: https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/717/58